# Group or union Entity Framework objects to return single object for each group?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm wondering if this is even possible in EF6, vb.net

My model contains objects for reminders, for one given reminder i can have many objects / rows in the dataset, typically one for each type of reminder that was sent for that particular event.

An idea of my data set would include similar to the following:

```
| ObjectID (PK) | EventID  (FK)   | EventType (Enum) |     Outcome (Enum) |
| 11111         | 1234            | SMS              |     Pending        |
| 11112         | 1234            | Email            |     Complete       |
| 11113         | 5678            | Email            |     Complete       |
```

Each object has a PK that is unique and an event ID that groups together related reminder objects. I'm trying to merge or group the items together by EventID such that one object is returned to the UI for each unique eventID returning all the eventTypes into one object that can be binded to by a grid in the UI.

Expected output:

```
Row 1: 1234  |  SMS Email | Pending Complete|
Row 2: 5678  | Email   | Complete |
```

So i started to try and work it out in my query:

```
 Dim SomeEvents = (select from db.reminders).GroupBy(Function(g) g.EventID).Select(Function(s) 
s.first()).ToEnumerable()
```

I can group them by the EventID's and then grab the first row, but i cant figure out how to grab the related items, is it possible to do this from the EF query and return to an anonymous type?

```
.Select(Function(s) New With {Key .EventID = s.EventID, 
     Key .Outcome = "Pending", "Complete" })
```

I can't work out how to return the EventTypes or Outcomes as a list of enums/strings/etc in an anonymous type.

Is this even possible?

The other approach would be to create a data transfer object class, select objects from the model into new objects from the DTO and return those to the UI, this is considerably more work, and there is not any business logic i'm trying to implement, just attempting to present the items as 1 row as opposed to multiple rows.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have an output like `SMS (Pending) | Email (Complete)`. Now it's easy to lose the relationship between type and outcome.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes - But i can't work out how to select into the anonymous type after grouping by....

Answer (score 0):

I forget VB but

```
Dim SomeEvents = (select from db.reminders).GroupBy(Function(g) g.EventID).Select(Function(s) {Key .EventID = g.Key, Key .Outcome = String.Join("|", g.ToList()) } ).ToEnumerable()
```

also, you can add additional `"|"` if you want.
`"|" + String.Join("|", g.ToList()) + "|"`

Comment: Still having an issue: In the anon object generation New With {Key .EventID s.EventID} - It won't let me select s.EventID, or g.EventID (EventID is not a member of IGrouping (Of Guid?, Remidners)